# Rails default data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Every time I create a new company record in rails, I need to add some default (blank) contact records at that company. Front Desk, Receiving, HR, IT and so on...they won't have any data in them besides the name, just a placeholder for the user to fill in later.

So, my company model has_many contacts, and contacts belong_to company. The contact records are static and the same for every new company that gets added, but I need to pre-populate the contacts table with data, so my users don't have to.

I've read a lot about seeding the database, but I won't be able to use the terminal every time a user dynamically creates a company, and it needs to be dynamically tied to that company, the records are not agnostic. Seeding doesn't seem to be the right thing. How should this be done?

Comment: As part of creating the company?

Comment: Yes, so as the company is created, the subordinate contact records are created too.

Comment: Right--I'm saying do it as part of creating the company.

Comment: Completely agree. How?

Answer (score 3):

you should use a `before_save` filter, which checks if an attribute is empty, and otherwise set it to the default.

Using a `before_save` will guard against deletions later on.

But be careful only to do this for fields which will never be empty.

```
 class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :contacts

   before_save :add_defaults

   def add_defaults
     contacts ||= Contact.default_list  # this only sets it if it's nil
     # you can implement Contact#default_list as a method, or as a scope in the contacts model
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

What about [after_create](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_create) callback in `Company` Model?

Smth like this:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts

  after_create :add_contacts

  def add_contacts
    contacts.create(name: "Some name", phone: "...", ....)
  end
end
```

Comment: Great, but the #code here part is what I don't know how to do. If it is in a form, entered by the user, I get it, but what about in just code? Create a new contact object, assign attrs to that? That's where I'm unclear.

Comment: @mcrtr It's no different than with a form, instead of using params, you use attributes, like `contacts = [ Contact.create(name: 'Receiving'), Contact.create(name: 'Front Desk'), ... ]` although I agree with Tilo's idea of keeping the default contacts isolated from the company itself--if it's reasonable to do so, e.g., doesn't depend on company type or something.

Comment: @mctr added some example. @Dave Newton - it's better to use `contacts.create` instead of `Contact.create` to set association.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't show up in the database. Do I have to call save or something? I added the company_id to the create(), is that right?

Comment: after_create :add_contact_defaults

def add_contact_defaults
    contacts.create(name: "Front Desk",company_id: @company.id)
end

Comment: Try `def add_contact_defaults self.contacts.create(name: "Front Desk") end`

Comment: Just checking I am adding this code to the model, NOT the controller, right? It isn't working at all.

Answer (score 0):

Although it notionally exists for generating test data, the FactoryGirl gem is very useful for this purpose. Use it in conjunction with the `after_save` approach mentioned here, and you'll have a nice place to centrally define your blank records.